# Why don't img directives apply to images inserted with ::before?

Tags: css

This html

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

and this CSS:

```
li {display:table-cell; border:1px solid black;}

li:before{
  content: url(http://i.imgur.com/7qZR5GX.png);
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

produce the following, as intended:

[image: correct output]

Fiddle of above example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Udg6J/

However, if you change the CSS to the following:

```
li {display:table-cell; border:1px solid black;}

li img {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

li:before{
  content: url(http://i.imgur.com/7qZR5GX.png);
}
```

it no longer works:

[image: not working]

Fiddle of that example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kLyu/

### Question

I thought that `content: url(http://i.imgur.com/7qZR5GX.png)` was equivalent to inserting an `<img>` tag with that src into the html?  So why does the `li img` CSS directive not apply to the content created with `:before`?

I want to understand why the two examples above are not equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li img { ... }`

Your image is not a child of LI, it's a pseudo-element of LI itself. It is not actually in the DOM, so normal CSS rules do not apply.